# What .[Date] function at the end of date column fetch in DAX query in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have one DAX code:

```
TOTALYTD(SUM('Table_name'[Sales_column]), 'Table_name'[date].[Date])
```

In the above query, Table_name is a table that has one date column which is the date type column, and is data Hierarchy. I am confused about the **.[Date]** function at the end, what it will give, the latest date from data or today's date?

Answer (score 0):

It will give you the date column from the hidden date table that was created automatically for that column as a result of auto date/time under Time Intelligence in the settings. Ideally, you want to disable this feature and have a dedicated date table otherwise a hidden date table is created for every date column in your whole model which is not necessary. This video will help you understand why the .[Date], .[Month] etc options appear but essentially, they are giving you the option of picking which value is returned from the hidden date table for your date column.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP23ws8H0XE

Comment: Thank you @davidebacci for the video link and quick reply. I got the idea of a hidden date table but my query remains the same what **.[Date]** will fetch from the table, like 
`TOTALYTD(SUM('Table_name'[column_name]), 'Table_name'[date_table].[Date])`
What will it take as a date if there are many years in the date table from 2016 to 2024 since it calculates the year-to-date total it should take only 2024-year records and if 2024 is missing then will it take the latest date or today's date?

Comment: It will just fetch the date in the current context. If you place the date column in a matrix, that will be the date fetched for each row.